# SQL Query, What am I doing wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi there fellas I'm trying to do this query but I am having trouble with it. Could anyone give me a hand I'll list below what I've done.

1. How busy each optometrist has been. Your SQL statement should return the full names of all optometrists, and the total number of appointments they have conducted. You must use the word ‘Optometrist’ not the positionID to select optometrists in your statement. Note that even optometrists with zero appointments should be displayed in the results.

   What I've done..

   ```
   SELECT firstName, lastName, optometristID, COUNT(optometristID)
   FROM employee
   LEFT JOIN appointment ON employee.employeeID=appointment.optometristID
   GROUP BY (optometristID)
   ```
2. The full name, email and primary phone number and total number of invoices for all customers in ascending order of last name. Note that even customers with zero invoices should be displayed in the results.

   What I've wrote..

   ```
   SELECT c.firstName, c.lastName, c.primaryPhone,
   (SELECT count(*) from invoice where customerID = c.customerID) as numInvoices
   FROM customer c, invoice i
   WHERE c.customerID = c.customerID 
   ORDER BY lastname ASC
   ```

Thank you!

Comment: please post the table and some sample data on sqlfiddle.com with your expected result on the question.

Comment: Also - what are your current queries returning?

Comment: You are joining customer customerID on customer customerID.

Comment: What are the problems you are getting while you run the queries? And show us your table structure.

Comment: My first query shows all the optometrist and their optometristID. But for some reason it is also showing 1 salesperon and their optometristID is NULL. Can anyone elaborate? Cheers

Comment: OK first, do not ever use implicit syntax again, it is a SQL antipattern. Learn to use explicit joins. YOu wil do better inteh long run at learning to query.  Next even though mysql allows you to group by only 1 field, never do that either, you will get inconsistent results and you should understand the correct way to group by that every other database uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is ok for me

The second should be either

```
SELECT c.firstName, c.lastName, c.primaryPhone,
(SELECT count(*) from invoice where customerID = c.customerID) as numInvoices
FROM customer c
ORDER BY lastname ASC
```

OR

```
SELECT c.firstName, c.lastName, c.primaryPhone,
count(i.customerID ) as numInvoices
FROM customer c left join invoice i
on i.customerID = c.customerID 
group by c.customerID 
ORDER BY lastname ASC
```

The last one should be faster

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much you've fixed query two. My first query shows all the optometrist and their optometristID. But for some reason it is also showing 1 salesperon and their optometristID is NULL. Can anyone elaborate? Cheers

Comment: Replace the LEFT JOIN with JOIN

Answer (score 0):

In second query you have to write

```
WHERE c.customerID = i.customerID
```

Instead of

```
WHERE c.customerID = c.customerID
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much you've fixed query two. My first query shows all the optometrist and their optometristID. But for some reason it is also showing 1 salesperon and their optometristID is NULL. Can anyone elaborate? Cheers

Comment: YOu need a where clause to specify that you only want Optometrists. Do you havea a field with employee type?